# JFrame does not wait for JOptionPane to execute

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I am working on a project in which I create a simple game of Ping Pong. If a player wins, I would like that a JOptionPane  pop up asking if the user would like to play a new Game or stop playing. When I add the JOptionPane, the method does not wait for the user to select a button, but keeps going and keeps creating JOptionPanes until it returns a Stack Overflow Error. The code that controls it is

```
int rightMinLeft = Right_Player_Score.getNumber()-Left_Player_Score.getNumber();
boolean rightWon = Right_Player_Score.getNumber() > 20 && rightMinLeft > 1;
if(rightWon)
{
  Object[] options = {"New Game", "Finish"};
  int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Right Player has won", "Game Over", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
  if(i == 0)
  {
    reset();
  }
  else
  {
    GameOver = true;
  }
}
else if(Left_Player_Score.getNumber() > 20 && Left_Player_Score.getNumber()-Right_Player_Score.getNumber()>1)
{
  Object[] options = {"New Game", "Finish"};
  int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Right Player has won", "Game Over", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
  if(i == 0)
  {
    reset();
  }
  else
  {
    GameOver = true;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here is the full method:

```
public void update(Graphics window)
 {
  paint(window);
 }

 public void paint(Graphics window)
 {
   try{
   if(pause)
   {
     Right_Player_Score.draw("Right Player Score", window, 600, 20);
     Left_Player_Score.draw("Left Player Score", window,  0, 20);
     leftPaddle.draw(window);
     rightPaddle.draw(window);
     if(U.LELatch(keys[4]))
     {
       pause = false;
     }
   }
   else
   {
     ball.moveAndDraw(window);
     leftPaddle.draw(window);
     Right_Player_Score.draw("Right Player Score", window, Color.WHITE, 600, 20);
    Left_Player_Score.draw("Left Player Score", window,  Color.WHITE, 0, 20);
    int LeftPaddleBottom = leftPaddle.getY()+(leftPaddle.getHeight());
    int RightPaddleBottom = rightPaddle.getY()+(rightPaddle.getHeight());
    int LeftPaddleTop = leftPaddle.getY();
    int RightPaddleTop = rightPaddle.getY();
    boolean inRangeLeft = ball.getY() > LeftPaddleTop && ball.getY() < LeftPaddleBottom;
    boolean inRangeRight = ball.getY() > RightPaddleTop && ball.getY() < RightPaddleBottom;
    if(ball.getX()<=10)
    {
     ball.setXSpeed(-ball.getXSpeed());
     Right_Player_Score.increment();
    }
    else if(ball.getX()>=790)
    {
      ball.setXSpeed(-ball.getXSpeed());
      Left_Player_Score.increment();
    }
    else if((inRangeLeft && ball.getX()<=leftPaddle.getX()+leftPaddle.getWidth()))
    {
      ball.setXSpeed(-ball.getXSpeed());
      numTimes ++;
    }
    else if(inRangeRight && ball.getX()>=rightPaddle.getX())
    {
      ball.setXSpeed(-ball.getXSpeed());
      numTimes ++;
    }

    if(!(ball.getY()>=10 && ball.getY()<=450))
    {
     ball.setYSpeed(-ball.getYSpeed());
    }

    if(keys[0] == true)
    {
     leftPaddle.moveUpAndDraw(window);
    }
    else if(keys[1] == true)
    {
     leftPaddle.moveDownAndDraw(window);
    }
    else
    {
      leftPaddle.draw(window);
    }
    if(keys[2] == true)
    {
      rightPaddle.moveUpAndDraw(window);
    }
    else if(keys[3] == true)
    {
      rightPaddle.moveDownAndDraw(window);
    }
    else
    {
      rightPaddle.draw(window);
    }
    int rightMinLeft = Right_Player_Score.getNumber()-Left_Player_Score.getNumber();
    boolean rightWon = Right_Player_Score.getNumber() > 20 && rightMinLeft > 1;
    if(rightWon)
    {
      Object[] options = {"New Game", "Finish"};
      int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Right Player has won", "Game Over", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
      //window.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      //window.drawString("Right Player has won",200,400);
      //Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
      //int i = 1;
      if(i == 0)
      {
        reset();
      }
      else
      {
        GameOver = true;
      }
    }
    else if(Left_Player_Score.getNumber() > 20 && Left_Player_Score.getNumber()-Right_Player_Score.getNumber()>1)
    {
      Object[] options = {"New Game", "Finish"};
      int i = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Left Player has won", "Game Over", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
      //window.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      //window.drawString("Left Player has won",200,400);
      //Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
      //int i = 1;
      if(i == 0)
      {
        reset();
      }
      else
      {
        GameOver = true;
      }
    }
    Right_Player_Score.draw("Right Player Score", window, 600, 20);
    Left_Player_Score.draw("Left Player Score", window, 0, 20);
    if(numTimes == 10)
    {
      numTimes = 0;
      if(ball.getXSpeed() == Math.abs(ball.getXSpeed()))
      {
        ball.setXSpeed(ball.getXSpeed() + 1);
      }
      else
      {
        ball.setXSpeed(ball.getXSpeed() - 1);
      }
      if(ball.getXSpeed()>MAXSPEED)
      {
        ball.setXSpeed(MAXSPEED);
      }
    }
    pause = U.LELatch(keys[4]);
   }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
   }
 }
```

This is used in "public class GUI_Controller extends Canvas implements KeyListener, Runnable"

Note: The commented portions are a stopgap way of getting the user to at least see something.

Comment: Could you post more of your code (at least the full method)?  The call to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` should block, so it's possible your problem lies outside this chunk of code.

Comment: Your painting code is wrong. The code is based on an AWT application and you are writing a Swing application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is because you are overloading the `paint(Graphics g)` method.

From the [`paint(Graphics g)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) JavaDoc

> This method is called when the contents of the component should be painted; such
>   as when the component is first being shown or is damaged and in need
>   of repair.

In your case, what is likely happening is the call to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` results in a `JDialog` showing over your `Canvas` which triggers another call to `paint()`.  That in turn causes another call to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` triggering another a call to `paint()` and so on...  This will continue until you get a `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError`.

In practice, `paint()` gets called quite frequently so it should be very efficient.  Typically only your custom drawing should be done in the `paint()` method.

Other logic should live in different methods.  You should move the logic for your scoring and user interaction outside of the `paint()` method and leave just the drawing in place.

***Edit:***  Without seeing more of the code I can't give you a specific recommendation of where to move the logic which is not directly concerned with painting.  You might find it helpful to review the [Java Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) section on [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this as soon as I have time to get back on my laptop

Comment: +1, the OP is using AWT style of painting for a Swing application which is not a good idea. Custom painting should be done on a JPanel (or JComponent) by overriding the `paintComponent()` method and then add the panel to the frame. As mentioned the Custom Painting tutorial shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to give the `JOptionPane` your current frame as the first parameter instead of `null`.

Comment: Tried that, but it still has the same behaivior. The only different thing is that the JOptionPane now is in the center of the JFrame rather than the screen

Comment: Yes. It just gets redisplayed a few hundreds of times

Comment: I just noticed what Jason Braucht wrote in his answer. It should be because it is in the `paint()` method